# Differences between Azure Block Blob and Page Blob?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

As I recently started mingling around with `Windows Azure`, I've came up to a situation where, which one to go for between the `Block Blob` & `Page Blob`. I'm currently in progress of uploading some text, csv or dat files to a blob storage and then do a `MapReduce` program for it using my C# program. Yes I've gone through an [article](https://sites.google.com/a/cloudenablers.com/blog/windowsazure/block-blob-page-blob).

But couldn't get a clear idea from them. To cut short, `Block Blob vs Page Blob`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The differences are very-well documented on msdn, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee691964.aspx). TL;DR:

- *Block* blobs are for your discrete storage objects like jpg's, log files, etc. that you'd typically view as a file in your local OS. Max. size <strike>200GB</strike> 4.77TB. Regular (non-Premium) storage only.
- *Page* blobs are for random read/write storage, such as VHD's (in fact, page blobs are what's used for Azure Virtual Machine disks). Max. size 8TB. Supported by both regular and Premium Storage.

Note: Premium page blobs have specific sizings (unlike regular page blobs, which can be any size up to 8TB).

- 32GB
- 64GB
- 128GB
- 512GB
- 1024GB
- 2048GB
- 4096GB

Premium storage provides guaranteed IOPS and throughput, depending on the page blob size chosen (from 120 IOPS+25MB/s @ 32GB to 7500 IOPS+250MB/s @ 2048GB & 4096GB). Specific details around IOPS+throughput details are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-premium-storage).

Comment: Another small clarification @David, how could I view the files within a Blob Container? I tried using Azure Explorer, but couldn't find a way to view the files within it. Yes i can see the content but not the files.

Comment: @Kulasangar Please ask a separate question, and not as a comment, as it's unrelated to the original question (and answer).

Comment: Page blobs are not restricted to Premium Storage. I understand it is not what you are saying necessarily, but your answer could easily be interpreted that way.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thank you for the tl;dr.  I read that entire link and no where  in there does it state what you said about the blob type being something that can be treated as a discrete object similar to an object on your file system.  The entire article is dedicated to describing how Azure manages a block blob type which is fine but as most things with Azure, it does so without really identifying simple common use cases as you have done.

Comment: For log files, an append blob would be the better choice.

Answer (score 29):

[Davids answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29081340/1163423) points out the differences between page and block blobs. However there are also **Append Blobs**. In short:

- **Block Blobs**: For large objects that *doesn't* use random read and write operations. e. g.  Pictures
- **Page Blobs**: Optimized for random read and write operations. e. g. VHD
- **Append Blobs**: Optimized for append operations. e. g. Logs

Further reading: [Understanding block blobs, append blobs, and page blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)

Comment: Do you have the same operations available on all three of these blobs?  I.e. I take "optimized" to mean I can interact and write to them in the same ways, but certain write patterns will perform better.

Comment: @AaronLS They differ. You have inidividual clients (AppendBlobClient, BlockBlobClient, ...) with different functions

Comment: My opinion is I think it's better to describe them in terms of capabilities.  Saying something is "optimized for append" is different than saying "append only".  The former implies they are functionally identical, but have different performance profiles for different workloads.

Answer (score 19):

**Block blobs** 
Block blobs are used to hold text or binary files up to ~5 TB (50,000 blocks of 100 MB) in size. The primary use case for block blobs is the storage of files that are read from beginning to end, such as media files or image files for websites. They are named `block blobs` because files larger than 100 MB must be uploaded as small blocks, which are then consolidated (or committed) into the final blob.

**Page blobs**
Page blobs are used to hold random-access files up to 8 TB in size. Page blobs are used primarily as the backing storage for the VHDs used to provide durable disks for Azure Virtual Machines (Azure VMs). They are named `page blobs` because they provide random read/write access to 512-byte pages.

**Append blobs**
Append blobs are made up of blocks like block blobs, but they are optimized for append operations. These are frequently used for logging information from one or more sources into the same blob. For example, you might write all of your trace logging to the same append blob for an application running on multiple VMs. A single append blob can be up to 195 GB

Ref: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/Understanding-Block-Blobs--Append-Blobs--and-Page-Blobs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/connect-an-app-to-azure-storage/2-explore-azure-storage

Answer (score 14):

Block blobs let you upload large blobs efficiently. Block blobs are comprised of blocks, each of which is identified by a block ID. You create or modify a block blob by writing a set of blocks and committing them by their block IDs. Each block can be a different size, up to a maximum of 100 MB (4 MB for requests using REST versions before 2016-05-31), and a block blob can include up to 50,000 blocks. The maximum size of a block blob is therefore slightly more than 4.75 TB (100 MB X 50,000 blocks). For REST versions before 2016-05-31, the maximum size of a block blob is a little more than 195 GB (4 MB X 50,000 blocks).

Page blobs are a collection of 512-byte pages optimized for random read and write operations. To create a page blob, you initialize the page blob and specify the maximum size the page blob will grow. To add or update the contents of a page blob, you write a page or pages by specifying an offset and a range that align to 512-byte page boundaries. A write to a page blob can overwrite just one page, some pages, or up to 4 MB of the page blob. Writes to page blobs happen in-place and are immediately committed to the blob. The maximum size for a page blob is 1 TB.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/Understanding-Block-Blobs--Append-Blobs--and-Page-Blobs

Answer (score 3):

From Microsoft
**Block blobs** include features that help you manage large files over networks. With a block blob, you can upload multiple blocks in parallel to decrease upload time. Each block can include an MD5 hash to verify the transfer, so you can track upload progress and re-send blocks as needed.

When to use

Azure Files Provides an SMB interface, client libraries, and a REST interface that allows access from anywhere to stored files. You want to "lift and shift" an application to the cloud which already uses the native file system APIs to share data between it and other applications running in Azure.

Azure Blobs Provides client libraries and a REST interface that allows unstructured data to be stored and accessed at a massive scale in block blobs.

Azure Disks Provides client libraries and a REST interface that allows data to be persistently stored and accessed from an attached virtual hard disk.  You want to lift and shift applications that use native file system APIs to read and write data to persistent disks.

Answer (score 3):

Another answer from my perspective would be,

**Block Blob​**

- Defined by a list of blocks​
- Used predominantly to store “Objects”​
- 50K Blocks of up to 100 MB each = 4.75 TB ​
- Most object storage scenarios Documents, images, video, etc.

**Append Blob​**

- Added for Azure Data Lakes
- Can add a block of up to 4 MB in a single operation​
- Usage increasing significantly – Cloud logging, IoT data, Distributed systems synchronization, etc​

**Page Blob​**

- Collection of 512-byte pages optimized for random read and write operations
- Page aligned random reads and writes IaaS Disks, Event Hub, Block level backup

Comment: Block Blob and Block Level storage are two entirely different things. right? one is for small storage and another is for disks. Just wanted to confirm from you.