# How to determine weather Azure storage is Page or Block Blob type?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to configure an online backup to an Azure Storage account. Some of the files I am backing up are larger than 200GB, so I have to be using page Blob type storage.

I believe that, at the moment, this is the kind of storage I have configured; However, my backup of the files that are larger than this 200GB fails stating that the "block blob maximum size is 200GB."

How can I check what kind of storage my Azure storage is configured as? And, how can i ensure that in the future, I am configuring the correct type of storage?

Comment: Note: Aside from size differences, page blobs and block blobs serve different purposes (and have different characteristics). See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29081340/272109) for a bit more detail. TL;DR you cannot just swap out one type for the other.

Comment: I get that completely, but my hands are somewhat tied as I need backup that can hold more than 200GB in one blob.

Comment: Then you'll need to use software that knows how to split files across blobs. Or you'll need to use an attached disk (as a page blob, which gives you 1TB), or an attached RAID array of disks (letting you go beyond 1TB).

Answer (score 1):

An Azure Storage account can contain Block, Append and Page blobs in a same container. We do not any configurations on Account level or container level. The difference is we will need to use different APIs in SDK or implement with different REST APIs for the different type of Blobs. 
[image]

You can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135733.aspx for more info.

And according to your requirement, for those blobs will be larger than 200GB. You can divide them into several pieces of block blobs, and you can custom [`mimetype`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179414.aspx) of the blobs pieces to determine whether they are the piece of a special file.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you upload the files to Azure Storge, you specify what type of blob you want to create, either Page, Blob or Append Blob.

Ex:

```
CloudPageBlob blob = container.GetPageBlobReference("file name");
blob.Properties.ContentType = "binary/octet-stream";

blob.Create(size)
```

Then you have to divide your stream into pages and iterate over it and upload it to the blob.