# Would page blobs have any advantage over block blobs when doing only random reads?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

My app is sequentially writing data to Azure Storage block blobs and once a blob is written it does not get modified but parts of it are randomly accessed. I wonder if using page blobs instead of block blobs would have any advantage. I thought premium storage would be one but then realized block blobs support it too.

[A previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29081340/4964734) says that "Page blobs are for random *read/write* storage" but what about random *read-only* storage?

Comment: it would be great if you can provide your app writing data Type and Size to provide more relevant solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no significant advantage in your case.

- **Page blobs** are utilised for Azure Virtual Machine discs since they are designed for random read-write storage, like virtual hard discs (VHDs). Page blobs can, however, also be used for  read-only storage.
- **Block blobs**, are ideal for streaming and storing large amounts of data like text or binary files and are made up of blocks of data that can be managed individually.
- **Block blobs** also support premium storage, which offers **high-performance, low-latency storage for workloads** requiring a lot of I/O. when a block is uploaded to a block blob, it is not committed until the block is called Put Block List on the new blob. The blob is kept on the server for a week, after which it is rubbish collected if you haven't committed any new blocks or added any more to the blob.

  Block blobs are ideal for streaming and storing large amounts of data, while page blobs are optimized for random read-write operations. **Since your app is sequentially writing data and not modifying it, block blobs are a good fit for your use case**.

  Refer this @[SmiKar Software](https://www.smikar.com/differences-between-blob-types/#:%7E:text=Page%20blobs%20are%20optimized%20for%20random%20read-write%20operations,and%20are%20optimized%20for%20data%20that%20changes%20frequently.) blog which explains difference b/w Block blobs and Page blobs. Alos explains when to use these blobs.
- Azure Storage also provides [concurrency management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/concurrency-manage?tabs=dotnet) to ensure that multiple clients can access the same blob simultaneously without conflicts.